# Rounding dates in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I'd like to figure out the age of a person based on two dates: their birthday and the date they were created in a database.

The age is being calculated in days instead of years, though. Here's my query:

```
SELECT date_of_birth as birthday, created_at, (created_at - date_of_birth) as Age
FROM public.users
WHERE date_of_birth IS NOT NULL
```

The date_of_birth field is a date w/o a timestamp, but the created_at field is a date with a timestamp (e.g. 2017-05-06 01:27:40).

And my output looks like this:

```
0 years 0 mons 9645 days 1 hours 27 mins 40.86485 secs
```

Any idea how can I round/calculate the ages by the nearest year?

Using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Use the `EXTRACT` function.

Comment: Please tag the dbms you really use

Comment: Which SQL are you running? They vary dramatically in how they handle dates.

Comment: It looks like PostgreSQL? PostgreSQL handles simple date subtraction purely in days. You could look at http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff to see how you can subtract 2 dates properly. You could also try `age(timestamp, timestamp)` (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html)

Comment: Ah yes, my bad! We're using PostgreSQL @Manngo

Comment: @scotthanford Do you really mean the _nearest_ year (rounded up/down) or whole year?

Comment: @Manngo the latter (rounded down whole year), but honestly that level of accuracy doesn't matter too much for my current need. But good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, dates are handled very differently to MSSQL & MySQL. In fact it follows the SQL standard very well, even if it’s not always intuitive.

To actually calculate the age of something, you can use `age()`:

```
SELECT age(date1,date1)
```

Like all of PostgreSQL’s functions, there are variations of data type, and you may need to do something like this:

```
SELECT age(date1::date,date1::date)
```

or, more formally:

```
SELECT age(cast(date1 as date),cast(date1 as date))
```

The result will be an **interval**, which displays as a string :

```
SELECT age(current_date::date,'1981-01-17'::date);
-- 36 years 3 mons 22 days
```

If you just want the age in years, you can use `extract`:

```
SELECT extract('year' from age(current_date::date,'1981-01-17'::date));
```

Finally, if you want it correct to the *nearest* year, you can apply the old trick of adding half an interval:

```
extract('year' from age(current_date::date,'1981-01-17'::date)+interval '.5 year');
```

It’s not as simple as some of the other DBMS products, but it’s much more flexible, if you can get your head around it.

Here are some references:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html
- http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MS SQLServer than you could

```
CONVERT(DATE, created_at)
```

and than calculate difference in months like

```
DATEDIFF(month, created_at, GETDATE())/12
```

means you can use reminder in months to add or substract one year.

Comment: use cast instead of convert if there is extended feature requirement like the display format